# How do you rename the tab of a add-in in Excel when customizing does not work?

Tags: excel, excel-addins

I have an Excel add-in with a customised tab name that I am trying to rename. I have tried to rename it via File> Options> Customize Ribbons and accessing the Add-ins tab to rename, but it does not allow me to do so (greyed out).

In the Customize Ribbons options, the tab is identified as Add-in and not the name that is being displayed on the ribbons bar.

How would I go about renaming this Add-in?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Not enough info, but if it is a real add-in, should be an XLAM file somewhere... Try to edit that one. If it's just a custom menu called from personal macro workbook, or another workbook, names should be in the code. Search for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Foxfire! So I did search through the code of the XLAM file and it wasn't in it, which was why I was confused as to where the UI for the name could have been in.

It's alright though, I've managed to find what I need. Turns out the XLAM file could be unzipped to reveal the XML file, which was where the code for the custom ribbon name was in. All I had to do was edit the code there and I've renamed the tab.